# Looking for Microsoft .NET based Open Source Intranet Solutions

Tags: .net, open-source, intranet

Does anyone know of any Microsoft .NET based, open source, Intranet solutions?  I have not been able to find anything recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used DNN in the past. It worked really well for a small intranet. http://www.dnnsoftware.com/